# Create multiple modules in CocoaPods like in SPM

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

My library is composed by two modules:

- The library core in Swift
- A module in C which includes CHTMLSAXParser

This is the structure

[image]

Now in order to compile it in SPM I need to create two targets:

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLib",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyLib",
            targets: ["MyLib"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "CHTMLSAXParser",
            dependencies: []),
        .target(
            name: "MyLib",
            dependencies: ["CHTMLSAXParser"])
    ]
)
```

This is pretty straightforward: in MyLib a source swift file call `import CHTMLSAXParser` and everything works fine.

However I don't know what's the correct way to replicate the same behaviour with CocoaPods podspec file.

Any idea?

Comment: You want a podspec and a subpodspec. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried with subpodspec but it does not work https://gist.github.com/malcommac/31aea9a80bd5670ae0a8f606681003ea


It just can't recognize the module in my main lib:  
`  - ERROR | [MyLib/Core] xcodebuild:  /.../EscapeSpecialCharacters.swift:22:8: error: no such module 'CHTMLSAXParser'`

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered mixed Swift/ObjC modules limitation does not apply to CocoaPods. So in order to solve the problem:

1. I've created a single podspec package which includes both C and Swift files
2. Used `#if canImport(CHTMLSAXParser)?` to avoid importing it when no necessary (under cocoapods) without generating a compiler error.

More infos [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10212)